# Can't call on a function in $scope from inside the $http service in the same controller

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to move one of the function I had in my JS file to inside my Angular controller, since I'm calling on this function from inside the controller and it makes sense to put it there and not go to another file.

I can't seem to make the $http service know of this function (highlighter1)

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('Controller', function($scope, $http) {   

    $scope.highLighter1 = function(side, string, load, callback) {}

    $http.get('/comments')
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.comments = response;
        var allEl=[];
        var i;
        for (i=0; i<response.length; i++) {
            allEl.push(response[i]._id);
        }
        $http.post('/ranges', {"commentIds":allEl})
        .success(function(result){
            result.forEach(function(item){
                highlighter1(item.dataAction, item.rangyObject, true);
          })
        })
    });
})
})(window.angular);
```

I'm getting an error in the console that "can't file variable highlighter1", so I'm guessing that I need to somehow register it in a different scope of something like that?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a global or even local function. It's an attribute of `$scope`. So you need `$scope.highLighter1(...)`.

Also note the capital `L`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.